# Is this a proper implementation of async/await?

Tags: c#, async-await

Method which will upload a file asynchronously:

```
public async void UploadScreenshot(DateTime? date = null)
{
    var uploadTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => _ftp.UploadFile(_screenshotLocalFile,
                                                                 date.HasValue
            ? _screenshotRemoteFile.Replace("{1}", date.Value.ToString(Helper.StandardTimeFile))
            : _screenshotRemoteFile.Replace("{1}", DateTime.Now.ToString(Helper.StandardTimeFile))));
    await uploadTask;
}
```

Usage:

```
UploadScreenshot();
```

Is this a valid method to upload a file asynchronously?

Comment: depends on your definition of valid. On this context, await/async doesn't give you anything. As soon as you call UploadScreenShot(), another thread will be executed and your code won't wait until the uploading is finished, in order to actually await, you need to return Task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but why to make await inside  of method

```
public Task UploadScreenshot(DateTime? Date = null)
{
    var uploadTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
        _ftp.UploadFile(_screenshotLocalFile, date.HasValue 
                ? _screenshotRemoteFile.Replace("{1}", date.Value.ToString(Helper.StandardTimeFile))
                : _screenshotRemoteFile.Replace("{1}", DateTime.Now.ToString(Helper.StandardTimeFile))));

    return uploadTask;
}
```

Usage:

```
await UploadScreenshot();
```

Also as I know async methods returning void is not good practice, better to return Task/

Comment: What is the difference between `Task` and `Task<Task>`?

Comment: Task<T> - where T means type of Result property in returned Task instance. You don't need to return Task<Task>, because Task.Factory.StartNew already returns Task instance. And I expect that returning Task<Task> could make some problems by task chaining.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it has several issues:

1. `async void` should be used for event handlers only. In all other cases, you should use `async Task` (or `async Task<T>`), so that you can asynchronously wait until the method finishes and properly handle any error that happens during its execution.
2. Your method just wraps a synchronous `UploadFile()` method. If there is an asynchronous alternative (`UploadFileAsync()`), then you should use that instead.
3. You can make it more efficient by not using `await` and instead directly returning the `Task` you get from `StartNew()` (or `UploadFileAsync()`).